# Adding hexadecimal to string

Tags: c++, hex

I'm trying to add a single 1 bit to a string, however, it seems that I keep getting the char converted to an int. I've tried typecasting it to an unsigned char, but I think that it's still converting it.

```
string output = "abc";
output += 0x80;
for (char c : output) printf("%02x", c);
```

I keep getting 616263ffffff80. However, I'm trying to get it to be 61626380;

Comment: what do you mean by adding 1 bit? what output do you expect?

Comment: @IłyaBursov The expected output is given at the end of the question.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is your `printf`. It's using `%x` which expects a `unsigned int` value. However, your `c` value is `signed char`. And so this value is converted to the equivalent integer which happens to be 0xffffff80.

You can correct this in various ways:

1. Use unsigned value for your loop variable:

   ```
    for (unsigned char c : output) printf("%02x", c);
   ```
2. Cast the value to `unsigned char`:

   ```
    for (char c : output) printf("%02x", (unsigned char)c);
   ```
3. Use the appropriate format length modifier:

   ```
    for (char c : output) printf("%02hhx", c);
   ```